# fatal: 'user/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: gitlab

I created a repo in gitlab and set the user.name in a global way.

When I try to push my project, after inserting my password, I get the following error:

**fatal: 'user/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.**

**Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**

My .git/config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@gitlab.domain.tld:user/test.git
     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

output from "git remote -v:

```
origin  git@gitlab.domain.tld:user/test.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.domain.tld:user/test.git (push)
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
git push https://username:password@gitlab.com/user/test.git
```

I've seen some issues in the newer versions of git that give me trouble when I don't specify the username and password every time. I'm sure there's a way around it but I haven't figured it out yet. Git recommends rolling back to older versions, but I'm sure there is a less drastic way.

Comment: Doing that gives me _"No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
Everything up-to-date"_.

Comment: ok, by explicitly including the master branch it works. A bit cumbersome, but will have to do. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

In Settings you want to add with

```
git push https://yourusername:yourpassword@gitlab.com/user/test.git
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.